# Resolving ODE in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm trying to make a program to solve the following system with `ode23`:

> 2y’ + z’–y + 2z = 0
>   y’ + 3z’ –3y +z = 0

with initial values:

> y(0) = 1
>   z(0) = 0

and analytic solution:

> y= cos(x)
>   z= sin(x)

but when I change the variable 4:

```
function dy = eqdif2(t,y)
%2y’ + z’ –y + 2z = 0;
%y’ + 3z’ –3y +z = 0
% y(0) = 1, Z(0) = 0
% y=y(1), z=y(2), y'=y(3), z'=y(4)
dy = [-2*y(3)+y(1)-2*y(2);3*y(1)-y(2)-3*y(4)];
```

I have a problem with `ode23`, reporting only 2 solutions:

```
clc,clear;
yp = [1 0];  %initial values
options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-4);
[t,y]= ode23('eqdif2',[0 20],yp,options); 
ya=cos(x);
za=sin(x);
figure;
plot(t,y(:,1),'-');
figure;
plot(t,ya,t,za);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "report only 2 solution"? `y` and `dy` are 2-by-1, but you're trying to index into `y(3)` and `y(4)` for some reason. I'm guess that your code produces an error? If so, please provide it in the question. You have two first order ODEs. You'll need to decouple them. The state vector is only 2-by-1. Also, please format your question. I already cleaned it up once.

Comment: Yes I dont understand, how to make with only y(1) and y(2), but is the reason to use y(3) and y(4), but no found produce error

Comment: hello, at the moment nobody give me answer, if you can help me I will be greatful @hypfco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go...

The ODE are linear, we know it, there is an algebraic solution and so. For using `ode23` you need an `explicit` set, on the form -- ps. note the vectorial form usage on the dependent variable x and the independent variable t hereonforth:

> x'=f(t,x)

Which on this case is reduced to the trivial, but useless, set:

> x(1)' = x(2)
>   x(2)' = -x(1)

This is solved as:

```
f=@(t,x)([-x(2);x(1)]);
y0=[1 0];
% f(0,y0) %Check IC = y'
[t, x] = ode23(f,[0 pi*2],y0);
plot(t,x)
```

[image]
**However**, if we need or want or we are forced to solve directly the system as is -i.e. implicit-, we should have the set defined as - again, g can be a vector of equations:

> g(t,x,x')=0

by using `ode15i` - i standing for "implicit":

```
g=@(t,x,dx)([ 2*dx(1)+dx(2)-x(1)+2*x(2); ...
    dx(1)+3*dx(2)-3*x(1)+x(2)]);
y0=[1;0];
dy0=[0;1]; % kind of magic to find...
% g(0,y0,dy0) %Check IC = 0
[t, x] = ode15i(g, [0 pi*2],y0,dy0);
plot(t,x)
```

The solution is the same for both options...

Comment: if is possible i have one other cuestion , if the initial condition change to y(pi) = 1
z(pi) = 0 I have to change something ? @hypfco Thank you very much

Comment: I suppuse the change no influence initial value y0=[1 0] (but is no ok, for you comment),  and I don't know how adjust the plotting, @hypfco